# O365 - Export of total number of licenses

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, office365, license, export

Do you know how to export via PowerShell from O365 total number of licenses with following parameters ?

- change SkuID to friendly name
- number of active licenses
- number of used licenses
- if possible, also information if this license is payed monthly or yearly

I know how to export the second and third point:

> Get-MsolAccountSku | ft SkuPartNumber,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits

But I can not find out how to do the first and fourth :-( ..

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards, Standa

Comment: If it is not available via the UI then you can't get it via any language. If it is available in the UI, it could be coming from another source and like calculated properties, the PowerShell allows to create new columns, well, there's that... Yet your purchase type is not associated per user, it's per org subscription. See also [Find-Module -Name '*license*' | Format-Table -AutoSize]

Comment: I do not need per user. I do not want any user be in the outcome of this problem. I just need information about licensing. Nothing with users ..

And could you please more explain "See also [Find-Module -Name 'license' | Format-Table -AutoSize" ? I am new in PowerShell so I do not know what you mean by that ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can get the type of payment for each license (monthly or yearly).

But you can get the time when each license is about to expire through the script below:

```
./LicenseExpiryDateReport.ps1
```

In addition, you can refer to the following article, which seems to be more in line with your requirements:

[Export Office 365 License Expiry Date with PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-License-59e16536)

Comment: Since Microsoft Technet is under deprecation, you can access the linked source directly: [Export Office 365 license expiry date with PowerShell](https://o365reports.com/2020/03/04/export-office-365-license-expiry-date-report-powershell/)